# Can you print the name of an include as code is executed within it?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a little develpoment utility for myself to print queries and the name of the file they're executed within while locally working on my code.

Let's say I have this page:

```
<h1>Page</h1>
<?php include('file.php')?>
```

And file.php had a query within it

```
$query_clients = query('SELECT * FROM clients');
while($client = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

And `function query()` could optionally print the query $string

Is there a way that when the page loads, this could be the result?

```
<h1>Page</h1>
file.php
SELECT * FROM clients
```

So as `query()` gets executed, I could then print the file the `query()` function is being run from? That way I would be able to see the query that was executed, and the file it was executed within.

I realise I can use `get_included_files` to show all includes, but can I show the include name as it's executing?

I also don't want to have to turn the include into a string that prints, because that would required hundreds of lines of code to be changed, defeating the purpose of having a simple tool. Or having to create my own `include()` wrapper, like `include_then_print()`

`__FILE__` doesn't work for me as it just prints my includes/funcitons.php file
`$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` don't work as they just the current file name

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists in PHP, the only solution to this that I can think of is ultimately writing your own `include()` and `query()`.

Comment: Thanks mate, I thought as much but was hoping there was some function I wasn't aware of. echoing my queries as they're run let's me see every query in context and makes identifying optimizations faster. Xdebug is comprehensive but cumbersome.

Comment: how about using debug_backtrace such as ```print_r(debug_backtrace(1));``` would that help?

Comment: Amazing, that does seem to provide an array starting with the file the code was executed in. I'm trying now to incorporate it into my function, I'll post as an aswer once it's working. Or you can post your own and I'll select as correct answer.

Comment: You can use the magic constant `__FILE__` inside the file that you call.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ruperto, this does exactly what I want

```
$filename = debug_backtrace(1);
echo(reset($filename[0]));
```

Returns

```
C:\[localpath]\file.php
```